# Curl returns null sometimes after refresh php

Tags: php, api, steam

I use curl to get a json from steam about inventory and sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

I think it's about frequently requist

do anyone have a work around it?

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$res = curl_exec($curl_handle);
if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch));
$dec = json_decode($res, true);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Here is the curl I use

Comment: Cache the successful requests (to a file/etc), and use that cache as a fallback. If the end-point doesn't work reliably, your layer needs to add the resilience.

Comment: if you down rate the quistion plz say why!

Comment: but i dont wanna do a file for it i just wanna have a requist so if it gets any updates i wanna have it in real time not as a file

Comment: If you don't want to use a cache then you're only ever going to be as reliable as the third-party source that you're backing on to. If it doesn't work 100% of the time, then neither can you.

Comment: so it dosent exist any work around it? like change any requist data so they dont know its the same api call

Comment: had this problems 3 times now and it cant be just me that have this problem with apis that they sometimes returns null and its probebly in the third-party security so it must exist some way to change it so you can do many requists

Answer (score 0):

Connection time out is low, try whit more value like 10 second.
if not resolve, past exception error for more help.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
```

Comment: didnt change it :/

Comment: thats the url to the site i testing on

Comment: i can do a var_dump so u can se refresh like 5 times in a row and u get null

Answer (score 0):

try use code for showing header and find problem :

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$res = curl_exec($curl_handle);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_handle));

if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch));
$dec = json_decode($res, true);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: [http_code] => 429 : Too Many Requests, steamcommunity.com is limitd for request, you just cached and send low request